# Can not ping a particular IP

Tags: networking, iptables, dhcp

I am allocating IPs to 2 VxWorks based machines simultaneously using OpenDhcpServer, the machines send the DHCP request upon powering on. The server allocates the IPs, but I am not able to ping the second machine although the IP is correctly allocated. I logged into the machine using telnet and it confirms that the IP is allocated. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you can telnet to it, then DHCP (and by extension the client) works fine. The "second machine" probably has a firewall rule in place that is dropping [ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) (ping) packets.

It's not a problem per se, but if you must have ping access, then correct the offending rule.

Comment: no i can actually ping the second machine from another computer on which the DHCP was not running . Could it be the problem of the dhcp server i am using?

Comment: Successful pings or telnet to the IP indicate that the DHCP assignment is working fine. The DHCP server does not tell the DHCP clients how to respond to pings. Check the ACLs on routers, switches, firewalls, etc between the pinging device and the problem device.

Comment: I directly connect to the divice for telnet and connect via a siemens switch for pinging and assignment

Comment: Can you give more details on the client? Operating system could matter

Comment: VxWorks is the os on the machines it is a UNIX based OS with no GUI and runs on an ARM 32 bit processor